# GWT - How to read a (text)file on the server (or: how to get the servletContext in RemoteServiceServlet)

Tags: java, file, servlets, gwt

For my GWT/GAE app I have a very large text file that I want to be read on the servlet in a normal way (e.g. `Reader in = new InputStreamReader (VideoBroadcastServiceImpl.class.getResourceAsStream("com/myapp/resources/textfile")`)
like you would do it on your local machine. 
**The problem is that I get a NullPointerException in this line.**
I have read hints of a more complicated way to read a file that exists in the WEB-INF folder in a GWT project where I need the servletContext. Once I have the servletContext I can ask for the real path where the file exists. The problem of this way is that I need to implement the `getServletContext()` method by myself which is very easy in a HTTPServlet but not in a RemoteServiceServlet (the standard servlet of GWT for RPC calls which I also use).
Is there another easy solution to read a file on the server or can you give me an advice how I can get the servletContext in a RemoteServiceServlet?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A [`RemoteServiceServlet`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/server/rpc/RemoteServiceServlet.html) **is** an `HttpServlet`, so it has a `getServletContext()` method.

(you can also get the `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` with `getThreadLocalRequest()` and `getThreadLocalResponse()` respectively)

Comment: Okay, I figured it out why it didn't work. I always got an exception when I tried to get the servletContext in the servlet's constructor. Apparently the servletContext is only accessible in the servlet's methods. I wanted to read the text file in the constructor (to instantiate a list) because I only needed to create the list once when the user goes on my website. Thank you for your help!

Comment: How about using the servlet's `init` method?